# The application theme is not saved

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a code that switches themes. But if I restart the application, the standard theme is set. Help me how to make sure that the theme is saved, which was selected last time.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), KodeinAware, SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener  {

    override val kodein by closestKodein()
    private val fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient by instance()


    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private val locationCallBack = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(p0)
        }
    }

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(navController)

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController)

        if (hasLocationPermission()) {
            bindLocationManager()
        }
        else {
            requestLocationPermission()
        }
        //AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)

    }



    override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences?, key: String?) {
        if (key == "dark_mode"){
            val prefs = sharedPreferences?.getString(key, "1")

            when(prefs?.toInt()){
                1->{
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                }
                2->{
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                }
                3->{
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_TIME)
                }
                4->{
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
This my ListPreference

<ListPreference
            android:key="dark_mode"
            android:title="Темы"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
            android:entries="@array/dark_mode_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/dark_mode_entries_values"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you only apply the theme in `onSharedPreferenceChanged()`, which will only be called at the moment when the setting is modified. You should also do this in `onCreate` so the setting is applied every time the Activity opens. Since you're doing it in two places, you should break it out into a separate function.

I also cleaned your code a bit. Call this function inside `onCreate()`, and also call it inside `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` instead of the code you currently have in that function.

```
private fun applyDarkModeSetting() {
    val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    val settingValue = sharedPreferences.getString("dark_mode", null)?.toIntOrNull() ?: 1
    val mode = when (settingValue) {
        1 -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
        2 -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
        3 -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_TIME
        else -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY
    }
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(mode)
}
```

Comment: THANK BRO. ITS really work.